# How to know the value of a built-in variable in WiX Toolset

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2019

I know WiX Toolset have some built-in variables that you can use on your projects. A list of them can be consulted [here](https://documentation.help/WiX-3.10.1/bundle_built_in_variables.html).

But how can I know the value of a variable? For example, if I want to know what value stores LocalAppDataFolder variable, how can I do that from Visual Studio? Is there any command to output its value? I mean something like when outputting system environment variables values from command prompt: echo %Path%

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to know it for *your system*?

Cause the whole point of these variables is, that they're dependent on the OS installation and you should treat them as variable. In most cases it will point to: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local`, but since the location of the appdata folder can be controlled during system preparation, it could point to something completely different. Ultimately, this location is retrieved from the Windows Registry:

```
HKEY_USERS\DefaultUser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

Different built-in variables may use different sources to evaluate during installation.